# voting correction

Tags: support

I got a voting correction "out of the blue". It's not much so I don't care about the rep change very much. But I was wondering where (which answers/questions) and why it was applied. I haven't been very active in the past few weeks, and there was no significant reputation change so the sudden correction is rather strange. How do I get more information?

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362020/non-serial-voting-corrected#comment1207722_362020 possibly related - might have happened across the network. I have.. theories but nothing concrete and some of the information is 'private'.

Comment: thanks for the hint... yeah... curious if there will be an official statement.

Comment: Still chewing on throwing that a status review

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362059/135565 will post a proper answer later now that it turns out I was right and it's public 

Comment: Sounds plausible, it would have been interesting to see the questions/answers the votes were removed from...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially - [a user was found voting things randomly across the network to try to earn badges.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362059/135565) The user's votes were invalidated across the network, resulting in a 'serial voting corrected' message. The serial voting was *unusually* across the network and spread across many users - hence individual reputation change being for 1-2 votes unlike the more typical serial voting involving many votes for one user on one site.

I can't really share anything other than what's on the MSE post but this is probably the reason.